# Doctrine2 and the danger of PostLoad events when doing Iterate

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

In Doctrine2 documentation on events it says:

`Note that, when using Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery#iterate(), postLoad events will be executed immediately after objects are being hydrated, and therefore associations are not guaranteed to be initialized. It is not safe to combine usage of Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery#iterate() and postLoad event handlers.`

Why is it not safe?

Iterate basically hydrates rows on an iterator basis, so I don't get the difference.

AbstractQuery:

in iterate:
  `$this->_em->newHydrator($this->_hydrationMode)->iterate($stmt, $rsm, $this->_hints);`

in execute:
`$this->_em->newHydrator($this->_hydrationMode)->hydrateAll($stmt, $rsm, $this->_hints);`

hydrateAllData which calls hydrateRowData but makes snapshots:

```
    while ($row = $this->_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $this->hydrateRowData($row, $result);
    }

    // Take snapshots from all newly initialized collections
    foreach ($this->initializedCollections as $coll) {
        $coll->takeSnapshot();
    }
```

vs simply hydrateRow.

Is it about those snapshots?